# Can't locate the prompt error which happens when I try to build the source of opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I try to use Opencv and the extra package to detect gender by some face feature. But when I try to build a sample code, the error happens. The worse thing is that I can't locate the error.Could anyone help or hint me someting?

#### the error is：

```
c:\program files\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\private.hpp(48): fatal error C1189: #error:  this is a private header which should not be used from outside of the OpenCV library
```

#### the corresponding code is:

```
48.  #ifndef __OPENCV_BUILD
49.  #  error this is a private header which should not be used from outside of the OpenCV library
50.  #endif
```

#### note:

- I have known the error C1189 means the error is supplementary information added by hand. I'm bewildered to locate the __OPENCV_BUILD or get more useful information.
- the source is get from [opencv3.1.0](http://opencv.org/downloads.html) and the extra package [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib). I tried to use cmake but failed, so I just copy one subfile of *`face`* to the original opencv file. the `#include "face.hpp"` is okay but the error happens.
- I use VS2015 and Win10

Comment: The problem is you have just moved one file from the extra package into your source, then tried to include that file, whereas it appears that file is not intended to be included directly. Don't try to find `__OPENCV_BUILD`, instead try to figure out how to include the contrib package into the build properly.

Comment: en~Thank you for your hint~

Comment: But how to close this question?

Comment: @Franco, If the issue is resolved, you can answer your own question, then chose it as the correct answer.

Comment: @mannyglover I'm sorry. I give it up, without the solution. I want to close it, however, I don't know how to close.